# Numeric argument passed with jq --arg not matching data with ==

Tags: json, bash, parameter-passing, jq

Here is a sample JSON response from my curl:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "jobStatus",
  "jobStatus": [
    {
      "ID": 9,
      "status": "Successful"
    },
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "status": "Successful"
    },
   {
      "ID": 99,
      "status": "Failed"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to check the status of ID=2. Here is the command I tried:

```
cat test.txt|jq --arg v "2" '.jobStatus[]|select(.ID == $v)|.status'
```

response: there is none

I tried value `2` without quotes and still no result.

By contrast, if I try the command with a *literal* `2`, it works:

```
cat test.txt | jq '.jobStatus[]|select(.ID == 2)|.status'
```

response:

```
"Successful"
```

I'm stuck. Can anyone help me identify the problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**`jq` is data-type-aware**:

- `.ID`, as defined in the *JSON* input, is a *number*,
- but any *command-line argument* passed with `--arg` (such as `v` here) is invariably a *string* (whether you quote the value or not),

so, in order to compare them, you must **use an explicit type conversion**, such as with [`tonumber/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.4/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions):

```
jq --arg v '2' '.jobStatus[] | select(.ID == ($v | tonumber)) | .status' test.txt
```

---

Given that you're only passing a *scalar* argument here, the following solution, using `--argjson` (`jq` v1.5+) is a bit of an overkill, but it is an **alternative to explicit type conversion** in that **passing a *JSON* argument in effect passes *typed* data**:

```
jq --argjson v '{ "ID": 2 }' '.jobStatus[] | select(.ID == $v.ID) | .status' test.txt
```

---

[peak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41773512/45375) demonstrates that **even `--argjson v 2` works** (in which case comparing to `$v` works directly), which is certainly the **most *concise*** solution, but may require an **explanation**:

- Even though `2` may not *look* like JSON, it is: it is a valid JSON text containing a single *value* of type *number* (see [json.org](http://json.org)).

  - Specifically, it is the fact that `2` is an *unquoted* token that starts with a *digit* that makes it a number in the context of *JSON* (the JSON *string*-value equivalent is `"2"`, which from the shell would have to be passed as `'"2"'` - note the embedded double quotes).
- Therefore `jq` interprets `--argjson -v 2` as a *number*, and comparison `.ID == $v` works as intended (note that the same applies to `--argjson -v '2'` / `--argjson -v "2"`, where the shell removes the quotes before `jq` sees the value).
  By contrast, anything you pass with `--arg` is always a *string* value that is used as-is.
- In other words: `--argjson`, whose purpose is to accept arbitrary JSON texts as strings (such as `'{ "ID": 2 }'` in the example above), can also be used to pass number-string *scalars* to force their interpretation as numbers.
  The same technique also works with Boolean strings `true` and `false`.

---

<sup>Tip of the hat to [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak) for his help.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want to check for the JSON value `2`, you have a choice to make - either convert the argument of --arg to a number, or use --argjson with a numeric argument. These alternatives are illustrated by the following:

```
jq --arg v 2 '.jobStatus[] | select(.ID == ($v|tonumber) | .status' 

jq --argjson v 2 '.jobStatus[] | select(.ID == $v) | .status'
```

Note that --argjson requires a relatively recent version of jq.

Of course, if you want to "normalize" .ID so that it's always treated as a string, you could write:

```
jq --arg v 2 '.jobStatus[] | select((.ID|tostring) == $v) | .status'
```