# jq --arg passed variable to select() not working without hard code value?

Tags: json, jq

Hi I am trying pass variables to jq but don't understand why some `--arg` variables work and some don't.

```
jq --version
jq-1.6
```

Example doesn't work with `.Value <=$v` and instead returns all .Values even greater than 10 and not as expected less than or equal to 10

```
h=hostname
ip=ipaddress
value=10
jq -r --arg i $ip --arg host $h --arg v $value 'select(.Value <=$v and .ClientRequestHost == $host and .ClientIP == $i)' file.json
```

Does work if .Value is hardcoded in `select()` to 10 `.Value <=10` and filters output for .Value less than or equal to 10

```
h=hostname
ip=ipaddress
value=10
jq -r --arg i $ip --arg host $h --arg v $value 'select(.Value <=10 and .ClientRequestHost == $host and .ClientIP == $i)' file.json
```

In both examples the variables for $h and $i passed to jq select do work, just not the variable for $v ?

Answer (score 3):

Found my answer in that --arg passed variables are strings and not interpreted as numbers https://stackoverflow.com/a/41773407/272648 so need to be converted

```
jq -r --arg i $ip --arg host $h --arg v $value 'select(.Value <=($v | tonumber) and .ClientRequestHost == $host and .ClientIP == $i)' file.json
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use the command-line option `-—argjson`