# Unable to catch imageDigest where the tag contains a numeric argument using jq, but why?

Tags: string, variables, parameter-passing, jq, string-interpolation

Trying to extract ecr image digest using the imageTag.

```
base ❯ aws ecr list-images --repository-name itaig
{
    "imageIds": [
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:ec2ad330fadaf1ef05e30b8ba1ee5a92efb8b39c8d51bbcfb706b1b1a1981020",
            "imageTag": "latest"
        },
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:9377451ac4ea941e49d3176457b3d285d6418fec883a9a8fee87a491b79ac06a"
        },
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:1fb63f185c11a3300d394f83f8152d391b5f37ee3b17b73702296e979fb42576"
        },
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:4fc44daf69561482c9b00858b1a60e6590444703b75d49fed7d46c025520ddac"
        },
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:ce109ba9df0e566a4bd9d0a8311596b61def59d51c1b42455170dcb41451f4b0",
            "imageTag": "main-48"
        },
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:928950d4cab36d434f99e65bb75e65e4a6218760b1a32a08ac7212b2b6b9b9b0",
            "imageTag": "main-49"
        },
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:30a7f57f1a8aea4b00a441fff139806662342f0b584651231ed99738bf9d00b8"
        },
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:2319a7b3d5a030cc22efc06be780d6789cbf575822dd96bffbb550e3d20faefd"
        }
    ]
}

~/src/personal/aws-s3-lambda main ⇣
base ❯ TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER=49

~/src/personal/aws-s3-lambda main ⇣
base ❯ TRAVIS_BRANCH=main

~/src/personal/aws-s3-lambda main ⇣
base ❯ aws ecr list-images --repository-name itaig | jq -r --arg travis_branch ${TRAVIS_BRANCH} --arg travis_build_number ${TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER}  '.imageIds[] | select(.imageTag=="$travis_branch-$travis_build_number") .imageDigest'
```

If I don't use args, it works like a charm:

```
base ❯ aws ecr list-images --repository-name itaig | jq -r '.imageIds[] | select(.imageTag=="main-49") .imageDigest'
sha256:928950d4cab36d434f99e65bb75e65e4a6218760b1a32a08ac7212b2b6b9b9b0
```

But the relevant imageDigest isn't caught by jq.

I suspect it has something to with the travis_build_number, I think I need to use "tonumber" but I'm not sure where to place it in my query.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing 2 arguments to JQ, why don't we combine those on to just 1 on the bash-level like so:

```sh
jq -r --arg travis_search "$TRAVIS_BRANCH-$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER" '.imageIds[] | select(.imageTag == $travis_search) | .imageDigest'
```

---

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2e0pjbgM6B)

---

Example on my local machine:

```
$
$ jq '.' test.json
{
  "imageIds": [
    {
      "imageDigest": "sha256:ec2ad330fadaf1ef05e30b8ba1ee5a92efb8b39c8d51bbcfb706b1b1a1981020",
      "imageTag": "latest"
    },
    {
      "imageDigest": "sha256:9377451ac4ea941e49d3176457b3d285d6418fec883a9a8fee87a491b79ac06a"
    },
    {
      "imageDigest": "sha256:1fb63f185c11a3300d394f83f8152d391b5f37ee3b17b73702296e979fb42576"
    },
    {
      "imageDigest": "sha256:4fc44daf69561482c9b00858b1a60e6590444703b75d49fed7d46c025520ddac"
    },
    {
      "imageDigest": "sha256:ce109ba9df0e566a4bd9d0a8311596b61def59d51c1b42455170dcb41451f4b0",
      "imageTag": "main-48"
    },
    {
      "imageDigest": "sha256:928950d4cab36d434f99e65bb75e65e4a6218760b1a32a08ac7212b2b6b9b9b0",
      "imageTag": "main-49"
    },
    {
      "imageDigest": "sha256:30a7f57f1a8aea4b00a441fff139806662342f0b584651231ed99738bf9d00b8"
    },
    {
      "imageDigest": "sha256:2319a7b3d5a030cc22efc06be780d6789cbf575822dd96bffbb550e3d20faefd"
    }
  ]
}
$
$ TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER=49
$ TRAVIS_BRANCH=main
$
$ jq -r --arg travis_search "$TRAVIS_BRANCH-$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER" '.imageIds[] | select(.imageTag == $travis_search) | .imageDigest' test.json
sha256:928950d4cab36d434f99e65bb75e65e4a6218760b1a32a08ac7212b2b6b9b9b0
$
$
```

Comment: It's still not working for me...
`base ❯ aws ecr list-images --repository-name itaig | jq -r --arg travis_branch ${TRAVIS_BRANCH} --arg travis_build_number ${TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER}  '.imageIds[] | select(.imageTag=="$travis_branch-$travis_build_number") | .imageDigest'

~/src/personal/aws-s3-lambda main ⇣`

Maybe it has something to do with the arguments?

Comment: Please check this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772776/numeric-argument-passed-with-jq-arg-not-matching-data-with -> that's what I tried to achieve but to no avail, because of the dash between the two arguments

Comment: Why converting that argument when we can combine those before sending to JQ? Please see my edit and example.

Answer (score 0):

Using the form of invocation in the original question (`jq -r --arg travis_branch ${TRAVIS_BRANCH} --arg travis_build_number ${TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER} ...`), an appropriate jq program could look like this:

```
 .imageIds[] 
 | select(.imageTag == "\($travis_branch)-\($travis_build_number)")
 | .imageDigest
```