# Adding a record to JSON object after selecting on a condition

Tags: jq

I have the following json:

```
{
   "thermostats": [
      {
         "name": "Thermostat1",
         "identifier": 111111111111
      },
      {
         "name": "Thermostat2",
         "identifier": 222222222222
      }
   ]
}
```

I'd like to add the following `{default: yes}` to the one that I select.

```
{
   "thermostats": [
      {
         "name": "Thermostat1",
         "identifier": 111111111111,
         "default": "yes"
      },
      {
         "name": "Thermostat2",
         "identifier": 222222222222
      }
   ]
}
```

I have the following but haven't figured out how to add the record

`q '.thermostats[] | select (.identifier == "1111111111")`

I've tried `. += {default: yes}` `| . += {default: yes}` `|= . +` but I'm going off the wrong track.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the quote marker `"` on the numeric type you are trying to search. Quotes should apply only when selecting/matching string types.

Use `+=` to add the object on the selected entry

```
(.thermostats[] | select(.identifier == 111111111111)) += {default: "yes"}
```

jqplay demo - https://jqplay.org/s/k5tForQ9HT

---

If you were to pass the match identifier as an argument, do refer to the answers at [Numeric argument passed with jq --arg not matching data with ==](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41772776/5291015), because `--arg` by default defines your argument to be string type, which needs to be modified inside your `select` to numeric type for comparison. So use `$thermoid|tonumber` or pass it as `argjson`

Comment: Or [`( ... ) |= ( .default = "yes" )`](https://jqplay.org/s/hinw2l2irI)